# Как представлена модель osi для веб приложений?

Tags: веб-программирование, сеть, http, osi

Все мы знаем что такое модель [OSI](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%A1%D0%B5%D1%82%D0%B5%D0%B2%D0%B0%D1%8F_%D0%BC%D0%BE%D0%B4%D0%B5%D0%BB%D1%8C_OSI)

И все знают что веб работает на семействе протоколов TCP/IP

Собственно вопрос, какие протоколы используются на 5(сеансовый) и 6(представительский) уровнях, используются ли они вообще, и чем все это определяется?

Comment: https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%A1%D0%B5%D1%82%D0%B5%D0%B2%D0%B0%D1%8F_%D0%BC%D0%BE%D0%B4%D0%B5%D0%BB%D1%8C_OSI

Comment: На шестом уровне JPEG используется, если Wikipedia не врет.

Comment: @VladimirGamalyan врет

Comment: @VladimirGamalyan ASCII, EBCDIC и JPEG - это вообще не протоколы. И они ну никак не могут быть ниже HTTP...

Comment: да на википедии трешак)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

На сеансовом уровне работает протокол TLS. На уровне представления на данный момент протоколов нет.

Также надо помнить, что модель OSI - очень старая модель, и предсказать будущее развитие интернета они не могли. В частности, давно уже, фактически, появились уровни еще выше прикладного. Поверх HTTP работают протоколы WebSocket, XML-RPC, JSON-RPC и SOAP. Поверх веб-сокетов тоже много чего работает, даже VPN есть.